# Rails Edit Form and jQuery UI Datepicker

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, forms, datepicker

I'm using the Simple Form gem to handle my forms. I've got a few date selection inputs that I'm using the datepicker from jquery ui on. These work fine when adding a new record, but when I try to update a record via my "edit" action, the datepicker will not update the input. When I click, the calendar pops up, but when I select a date nothing happens. Has anybody run into this problem before?

**my view:**

```
 <%= simple_form_for(@task, :remote => true) do |f| %>
  <%= f.association :user, :collection => User.where(:company_id => current_user.company_id), :prompt => "Unassigned", :label_method => :first_name, :value_method => :id, :label => false %>
  <%= f.input :date_due, :as => :string, :label => false, :input_html => { :value => @task.date_due.strftime("%B %d, %Y") } %>
<% end %>


<script>
  $(function(){
    //DATEPICKER FOR NEW TASKS
    $('input#task_date_due').datepicker({
      dateFormat: "MM d, yy",
      minDate: 0,
      maxDate: "<%= @task.phase.date_due.strftime("%B %d, %Y") %>"
    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: What does the actual HTML look like for the form and for the datepicker function when you inspect it? Is maxDate set correctly in the HTML?

Comment: It all looks fine. I even tried removing the maxDate option to see if that was causing problems and no luck.